# Can I create web api using express.js and not have node.js installed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express

I am currently in the process of creating a portfolio website for myself but due to hosting restrictions, I cannot make use of Node.js.

I know Angular can run on any web server, but is it possible to make use of Express.js to create web api's with relying on Node.js to run these web api's using Express.js?

If not, is there an alternative solution to create web api's that I can call using Angular and later for my mobile version of my website?

Please note that my shared hosting runs using cPanel.

Comment: express is a `web framework` for node.js which means you need to have access to node. Which other language options are avail in your hosting, I'd suggest python/django/flask

Comment: @Saawant I am running on a shared platform under cPanel, so I am not sure but, I suppose I could develop the api's using PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use Express without NodeJS by definition so you have to deploy your backend somewhere else in you want to use it.

I suggest giving a look [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/): you could write your backend using [http cloud functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) in express without paying anything until a reasonable amount of traffic (after that, is pretty cheap). You could also get rid of cPanel and deploy your frontend there via [Firebase hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting).

Answer (score 2):

As per definition **Express.js, or simply Express, is a web application framework for Node.js** so you can't do that. Alternatives would be to use a different backend language. 
That also depends if your server supports them, for example, you can go with **.NET CORE**

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try to build at first a web application with express. Of course you can create a web app without express if you need it. With express and Node.js I created a MySQL REST API. With HTML and Ajax you can fetch the Data from the API. So you can create two applications. One application where you need to run Node.js because it`s much easier to create a REST API with express. The second one is fully without Node.js.

Maybe there are better solutions, but inside each Web Application you can than but you can then access this API in any web application using jQuery. It doesn't matter if it is written with PHP, ASP.Net Core, Java EE / EE4J. You can also access this API in Ruby, Angular, React, Vue etc. using an AJAX request.

In some scenarios you can't start Node.js as a server because an application is already running on apache2 or nginx. There this would be a workaround to use something like this. For example, one could also integrate applications with HTML+JS in a CMS system that accesses other database tables and thus extend such a system without an iframe.

So can be helpful for few scenarios. Now just doesn't get around the actual goal of doing without Node.js completely or even express. But why are there REST APIs? So that you can query the data and incorporate it somewhere else. Otherwise you would have to build a REST API with another technology. Especially in the example of accessing MySQL with JavaScript, this would not be quickly feasible.

If you are looking for a similar solution to separate the web app and the REST API, but you don't need Node.js, then you should really build a REST API with .Net Core or with another technology, depending on what is possible and installed on your server. It could be Java or PHP behind it or Ruby.

The API that provides the REST access does not have to be written in JavaScript. You only need to be able to access it with JavaScript. So you can use many different approaches to access JSON data. I hope that in the short time with my bad English I have explained the basic idea, how to proceed stylistically and where advantages exist in REST interfaces.

With this, it should be self-explanatory that you don't have to use NodeJS and Express, but with JavaScript it's a pleasant solution. Only you have to ask yourself if a JavaScript application has to provide this interface at all or if in the end only a JavaScript application has to access this interface. Very big difference.

Comment: And of course you can create a MVC pattern or other things with plain JavaScript which could make some different stuff easier. In my studies we also had to build the whole thing ourselves using jQuery and HTML. Best with the Observer pattern. Routing is also possible without any frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

For backend rest api you can use golang with gorilla framework. Golang simple keyword and easy to learn.best important point is performance. If your server support golang you can use golang for backend..

Answer (score 0):

ExpressJS is NodeJS framework so it's impossible to create an API without NodeJS.
Angular is front-end framework so you can host it on web hosting server.
If you need to create back-end APIs, you can use other clouding host servers that support NodeJS.

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly simple to build this with just the net/http package. Set up a router that handles various commands and deal with the response accordingly.